# Website infringement, a Clear Question deleted even with a clear answer!?

Tags: support

[How can I to solve
?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275198/how-can-i-to-solve-cos-x-2x/275210#275210)

The author, after receiving a clever answer to a question is deleted question!.
to do not let another person use answer

Q:cos2x=x
A:x=0.4501836113

This question was voluntarily removed by its author **after answer not befor!**.

**Question:**
I would like to get an approx. solution to the equation: $\cos x=2x$, I don't need an exact solution just some approx. And I need the solution without higher mathematics (without derive and things like that :) ).

**Answer:**
if $\cos x=2x$ which means 
$$x=\frac {1}{2.22131587} \,rad,$$

$$x=28.65957881\,Grad,$$

$$x=25.79362093\,Degree$$

Comment: It's an answer. Clever?

Comment: In a case like this I am reluctant to jump to the conclusion that the OP deleted the question in an attempt to cover his/her tracks or some such questionable reason. That may have happened, but it is IMHO more likely that a new user simply does not realize how the site is supposed to work. They may be somewhat ashamed about having asked a simple question (or their faulty English?). And/or they may feel that they are somehow saving the common resources (like disk space on the server) by removing material that has according to their best judgement become obsolete.

Answer (score 5):

The OP has deleted the post. If there are no upvoted answers then it is possible for a registered user to delete a post.

If you feel that the deletion may have been an attempt to cover ones tracks, then it is a reasonable action to flag [practically any question; though better if you can find another post written by the user in question] and notify the moderators of this happening. You should include the link address of the question in your flagging text if you have the address handy; it will speed up processing.

Comment: already noted. I will undelete the question and answer.

Comment: @robjohn: Of course that a meta thread works just fine, but it's a public hearing when sometimes that's not the right thing to do.

Comment: i think that the deletion may have been an attempt to cover ones tracks.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: if what you're saying is that a flag is better in this situation, I agree completely.

Comment: @rob: This is exactly what I'm saying!